Female protagonist who discovered some new species of creature that lived in the atmosphere
The book was about a female protagonist who discovered some new species of creature that lived in the atmosphere and she discovered it because it moved slowly across the stars at night blocking light from them.
Then she somehow forms a group of explorers who go to space to study these creatures in a space ship sort of like a blimp but it rides up a cable like an elevator.
At some point they realize there’s a problem because they can see the cable and realize that the rocket keeping the cable taut has failed and they have to venture out and climb the cable to fix the rocket.
I think it was a series and I might have mixed the two books into one… I’m pretty sure it was a YA book I got from the school library in middle school circa 2010s

I believe this might be the Airborn series by Kenneth Oppel consisting of :

Airborn
Skybreaker
Starclimber

The male protagonist is Matt Cruse but the female is Kate de Vries.
Via Goodreads
Airborn

Matt Cruse is a cabin boy on the Aurora, a huge airship that sails hundreds of feet above the ocean, ferrying wealthy passengers from city to city. It is the life Matt's always wanted; convinced he's lighter than air, he imagines himself as buoyant as the hydrium gas that powers his ship. One night he meets a dying balloonist who speaks of beautiful creatures drifting through the skies. It is only after Matt meets the balloonist's granddaughter that he realizes that the man's ravings may, in fact, have been true, and that the creatures are completely real and utterly mysterious.

Skybreaker

Forty years ago, the airship Hyperion vanished with untold riches in its hold. Now, accompanied by heiress Kate de Vries and a mysterious gypsy, Matt Cruse is determined to recover the ship and its treasures. But 20,000 feet above the Earth's surface, pursued by those who have hunted the Hyperion since its disappearance, and surrounded by deadly high-altitude life forms, Matt and his companions soon find themselves fighting not only for the Hyperion—but for their very lives

Starclimber

Pilot-in-training Matt Cruse and his love interest, Kate de Vries, an expert on high-altitude life-forms, are invited aboard the Starclimber , a vessel that literally climbs its way into the cosmos. Matt secretly plans on asking Kate to marry him, but before they even set foot aboard the ship, Kate announces her engagement -- to someone else. Despite this bombshell, and Matt's anguish, they embark on their journey into space, but soon the ship is surrounded by strange and unsettling life-forms, and the crew is forced to combat devastating mechanical failure. For Matt, Kate, and the entire crew of the Starclimber , what began as an exciting race to the stars has now turned into a battle to save their lives.

